# Reading and Writing from Server in loop in the same time on Android

Tags: java, android, http, kotlin, httpurlconnection

I need to create a connection to the server and read messages from the server for some time. At the same time, I need to send a string to the server every X seconds to update the data. I am using `HttpUrlConnection` and the following code:

NTRIPClient.kt

```
class NTRIPClient {

private val bufferSize = ByteArray(64)
private val crlf = "\r\n"

private var inputStream: BufferedInputStream? = null

fun startConnection(gga: String, usbService: UsbService) {
    con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection?
    con?.doOutput = true
    con?.setChunkedStreamingMode(0)
    con?.setRequestProperty("Ntrip-GGA", gga)
    con?.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
    con?.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity")

    try {
        inputStream = BufferedInputStream(con!!.inputStream)
        var readBuffer = inputStream!!.read(bufferSize)
        while (readBuffer > 0) {
            usbService.write(bufferSize)
            readBuffer = inputStream!!.read(bufferSize)
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        con?.disconnect()
    }
}

fun updateGGA(gga: String) {
    try {
        val outputStream = OutputStreamWriter(con!!.outputStream)  //this line create error
        outputStream.write(gga + crlf)
        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Call NTRIPClient in ViewModel.kt

```
fun createNtripConnection(usbService: UsbService){
        ntripScope.launch {
            awaitAll(
                async {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createNtripConnection: START")
                    ntripClient.startConnection(currentGGA, usbService)
                },
                async {
                    delay(5000)
                    ntripClient.updateGGA(currentGGA)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

When I run the method `createNtripConnection` everything works fine, but when it comes time to execute the method `updateGGA` I get the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@5170b14c
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:203)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:129)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:750)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:622)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:475)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
        at com.hq.advian.newtwork.NTRIPClient.startConnection(NTRIPClient.kt:43)
        at com.hq.advian.viewmodel.ArViewModel$createNtripConnection$1$1.invokeSuspend(ArViewModel.kt:207)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
W/System.err:     at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:202)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:188)
        ... 14 more
```

If in the `updateGGA` at the very beginning I try to close the `inputStream`, on this line I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Can you help with this? Or there are other tools to solve this problem?

Comment: `At the same time, I need to send a string to the server every X seconds to update the data. ` That makes no sense as http protocol is not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution. `HttpUrlConnection` can't read and write data in the same time. To do this, you need to use a `Socket`. First you need to create a `Socket` and connect to the host:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL("{your_url/your_mount_point}").getHost());
Socket socket = new Socket(address, PORT_NUMBER);
System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
```

If you connected successfully, then in the console you will see `true`.

Now you have to open two streams to communicate with the server: `InputStream` and `OutputStream`:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Now you can send GET, POST and others requests. To do this, we will use a `PrintWriter`:

```
String requestMessage = "GET /{your_mount_point} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
output.println(requestMessage);
```

We use message `GET /{path} {protocol (HTTP/1.1 for example)}`. At the end of each line you must use CRLF `\r\n`. Then you can add the necessary headers according to the scheme:

```
output.println("{header name}: {header value}\r\n");

output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
output.println("Accept-Encoding: identity");
```

After that, you can read data from the server. In my case, this is an endless stream of messages, so I will use the following option:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
int readBuffer = input.read(buffer);
while (readBuffer > 0) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));
   readBuffer = input.read(buffer);
}
```

If during data reading you need to change the header, you can send the string to the server again:

```
output.println("Connection: close");
```

Full method looks like this:

```
void createSocket() {
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL("your_url/your_mount_point").getHost());
            Socket socket = new Socket(address, PORT_NUMBER);
            System.out.println(socket.isConnected());

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            String requestMessage = "GET /{your_mount_point} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
            output.println(requestMessage);
            output.println("Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0\r\n");
            output.println("Connection: Keep-Alive");
            output.println("Accept-Encoding: identity");
            output.println("\r\n");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[128];

            int readBuffer = input.read(buffer);
            while (readBuffer > 0) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));
                readBuffer = input.read(buffer);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful as I am building an ntripclient as well.